# Create new JSON value out of strings extracted from another

Tags: json, jq

I have a json file with the following input

```
{
  "Arg":"room=Rhasspy rhasspyName",
  "Results": [
  {
    "Name":"TV",
    "Internals": { },
    "Readings": { },
    "Attributes": {      "rhasspyName": "TV" }
  },
  {
    "Name":"dyTest01",
    "Internals": { },
    "Readings": { },
    "Attributes": {      "rhasspyName": "radio" }
  },
  {
    "Name":"enoAcPC01",
    "Internals": { },
    "Readings": { },
    "Attributes": {      "rhasspyName": "pc" }
  }  ],
  "totalResultsReturned":3
}
```

With `jq '.Results | .[] | .["Attributes"] | .rhasspyName' -r` I can get a list like

```
TV
radio
pc
```

How can I take this input and create a new json looking like

`{"Devices":["TV","radio","pc"]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them into an array and pair that with `Devices` key in an object.

```
$ jq '{Devices:[.Results[].Attributes.rhasspyName]}' file
{
  "Devices": [
    "TV",
    "radio",
    "pc"
  ]
}
```

To create a new file with that JSON value, redirect JQ's stdout to a file, like:

```
jq '{Devices:[.Results[].Attributes.rhasspyName]}' file > newfile
```